# How do I replace the value of an element with some compiled HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I compile some HTML with Angular, how can I replace the contents of an DOM element with the compiled HTML? Example:

```
var html = "<div>{{msg}}</div>";
var scope = $scope.$new();
var scope.msg = "Hello World!";
var linkFn = $compile(html);
var contents = linkFn(scope);

element.replaceContents(contents);//what is the actual syntax for this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the content from the element and append the newly compiled contents.

```
element.empty().append(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it seems like the element I have is a D3 element, not an Angular element. D3 Elements dont seem to have an `empty()` function. Do you know what the alternative would be in this case?

Comment: If you are inside a directive, you should have access to the raw HTML element.  If I recall correctly, D3 will provide the raw HTML element, have you tried `$(element).empty().append(contents)`.

Comment: That didn't work either. Actually I was wrong, I see that the element is actually defined earlier in the code as `element = document.createElement('i');`, so I guess its a raw DOM element. Any clue what I need to do in that case?

Comment: `$(element)` should suffice.  Is `element` ever appended to the browser DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The pure-javascript way is `element.innerHTML = contents;`

Comment: Doing that will remove the angular bindings because innerHTML will convert the DOM Fragment to a string (removing the bindings).  Keeping the DOM Fragment (which is what `$compile` produces.) intact, retains all bindings.